# Binary Search when no "fixed" answer...? (Font Sizing)

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

So I'm trying to figure out how best to implement a binary search algorithm to find the "optimal" font size for a piece of text to fit into a given space, **to the nearest 0.5pt**.

My understanding is this:

Say I have a starting user-defined font size of 40pt, I then check if it fits, if it does, great. Stop.

If it doesn't fit, half it to 20, see if that fits. If it does, then add half the step value (10) and try again with that value (30). If it doesn't fit, deduct half the value again (10), etc.

My issue is this: Say I know that the maximum font size that will fit is 11pt.

`40 x--> 20 x--> 10 ---> 15 x---> 12.5 x--> 11.25 x--> 10.50 ---> etc..
   -20     -10     +5      -2.5       -1.25      -0.75      +0.375`

But at no point will I end up with 11pt.. the decimal places will just get larger and larger.

How do I stop this from happening and enforce an "end point" that I know **will** fit?

Comment: "to the nearest 0.5pt", so round the font sizes you try to $0.5pt$.

Comment: But that doesn't really solve the issue, does it?! I mean, sure I'll have values rounded to 0.5, but I still won't know when to stop, will I?

Comment: You then have a discrete range of possible values. Whenever you have tried $k\cdot 0.5pt$ and $(k+1)\cdot 0.5pt$ and $k$ works but $k+1$ doesn't, you stop. If both work, then you come from either $(k+2)\cdot 0.5pt$ which then is known to not work, and you're done, or from $(k+3)\cdot 0.5pt$, which doesn't work, and then you test $(k+2)\cdot 0.5pt$. If both don't work, the situation is analogous. The point is that in each interval, you only have finitely many points, so the procedure is guaranteed to stop.

Comment: I see, I guess that answers my next question, which was, say that the maximum font size that would fit is 10.49pt, rounded it would alway zero-in on 10.50.
Right... now to try to figure out how to program it all.. :/